# AngularJS ng-click not triggering function in ui-gmap-window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-v1

I have a click event that I attach to google maps info window via an `<a>` tag. However, it won't trigger the function even though it says that is activated.

I tried adding `ng-app=""` and `ng-controler=""` unsuccessfully

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams,
            uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $cordovaGeolocation, $state, $firebase,
            $ionicModal) {
    var createMap = function(position){
        angular.extend($scope, {
            map: {center: {latitude: position.coords.latitude,longitude:position.coords.longitude},
                zoom: 13,
                markers: markersarray,
                options: {
                    // This is an example of a variable that cannot be placed outside of uiGmapGooogleMapApi without forcing of calling the google.map helper outside of the function
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    rotateControl: false,
                    zoomControl: false
                }, 
                events: {
                    click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                        var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                        Marker_Latt = e.latLng.lat();
                        Marker_Long = e.latLng.lng();
                        $scope.openModal();
                    }
                },
                markersEvents: {
                    click: function(marker, eventName, model, args) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < markersarray.length; i++){
                            if(markersarray[i].id === marker.key){
                                var content = '';
                                content += '<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl"><p>Added By: <a style="cursor: pointer;" [routerLink]="" (click)="navigatetoUser()">'+markersarray[i].username+'</a></p>';
                                content += '<p>Added On: ' + markersarray[i].date.toString() + "</p></div>";
                                navigateUserID = markersarray[i].userid;
                                createWindow(marker.get('map'), marker, content);
                               break;
                            }
                       }


                    },
                    dblclick:function(marker, eventName, model, args) {
                        console.log("double click!" + marker);
                    }
                },
            } 
        } );
    };

    $scope.navigatetoUser = function(){
        console.log("button clicked..");
        //$scope.data.selectedUserID = navigateUserID;
        //$state.go('userProfile', $scope.data);
    };
    function createWindow(map, marker, content){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
         });
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });
```

navigatetoUser() function is not triggered and I don't see any errors

---

Original code: '''

```
    <ui-gmap-window isiconvisibleonclick="true">
      <p> {{CurrentMakerTitle}}
        <a href="" ng-click="$root.navigatetoUser()"> 
         {{CurrentMakerUserName}}
        </a>
        <br>{{CurrentMakerDateAdded}}
      </p>
    </ui-gmap-window> 
</ui-gmap-marker>
```

''' I changed it to infowindow since multiple windows display the last click information –

Comment: you should bootstrap your app at the root `<html>` .why are you dynamically creating `ng-app`  in the for loop?

Comment: Also you have mixed up between the syntax of angularjs and Angular .Replace the below code `[routerLink]="" (click)="navigatetoUser()"` with `<a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-link="[]" ng-click="navigatetoUser()"></a>`

Comment: @Niladri `ng-link` is not a core AngularJS directive.

Comment: Did your original code not work? And then you decided to break it further by adding `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to the appended HTML?

Comment: Niladri & Georgeawg: Thank you both for the comments, either way (removing ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl") or not it still doesn't trigger the function. I also changed/tried ng-click & (click) - both show 'activated' when clinking on the link but won't call the function.

Comment: Looks like you put the code through a [cuisinart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisinart). The marker calls a function on $rootScope but the controller shows the function on $scope.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who commented, I manage to solve the problem by doing the following:

```
click: function(marker, eventName, model, args) {
    for(var i = 0; i < markersarray.length; i++){
        if(markersarray[i].id === marker.key){
            navigateUserID = markersarray[i].userid;
            var content = '<p>Added By:  <a id="Info_'+marker.key+'" style="cursor: pointer;" [routerLink]="">'+markersarray[i].username+'</a></p>'
            content += '<p>Added On: ' + markersarray[i].date.toString() + "</p>";
            createWindow(marker.get('map'), marker, content, marker.key);**
           break;
        }
   }
}
```

```
function createWindow(map, marker, content, key){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('Info_'+key+'');
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'click', function() {
                navigatetoUser();
            });
        });
    }
```